# Как получить "исходный код" страницы, которая генерируется программно

Tags: веб-программирование, php, парсер, html, javascript

Т.е. есть какая-то веб-страница, у нее есть инпуты и другие поля. Задача - получить в файл данные с этой страницы. Просто парсить не получается, т.к. при просмотре кода страницы видно, что значения полей там не указаны. Указаны только переменные, из которых они берутся, и т.д.

Я не очень силен в веб-программировании (да и в программировании в целом :) ), так что подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли как-то получить данные с такой страницы? )

Вот пример: 
На странице есть инпут со значением 34.70.
При просмотре его кода видим:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="*" data-val-regex-pattern="(-)?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?" data-val-required="" digitscount="2" name="**TARUF01**" type="text" valuetype="decimal">
```

Comment: Скорее всего данные подгружаются через AJAX, найти их можно с помощью консоли разработчика, на крайний случай пройдитесь поиском по страницы на предмет этих значений.

Comment: @kostyasxd, дайте ссылку на данную страницу. И тогда Вам быстро помогут :)